# JavaScript in requests package python

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

I want to get text from a site using Python.
But the site uses JavaScript and the requests package to receive only JavaScript code.
Is there a way to get text without using Selenium?

```
import requests as r

a=r.get('https://aparat.com/').text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the site loads content using javascript then the javascript has to be run in order to get the content. I ran into this issue a while back when I did some web scraping, and ended up using Selenium. Yes its slower than BeautifulSoup but it's the easiest solution.

If you know how the server works you could send a request and it should return with content of some kind (whether that be html, json, etc)

Edit: Load the developer tools, go to network tab and refresh the page. Look for an XHR request and the URL it uses. You may be able to use this data for your needs.

For example I found these URLs:

https://www.aparat.com/api/fa/v1/etc/page/config/mode/full
https://www.aparat.com/api/fa/v1/video/video/list/tagid/1?next=1

If you navigate to these in your browser you will notice JSON content, you might be able to use this. I think some of the text is encoded in Unicode e.g \u062e\u0644\u0627\u0635\u0647 \u0628\u0627\u0632\u06cc -> خلاصه بازی

I don't know the specific python implementation you might use. Look for libs that support making http requests and recieving data. That way you can avoid selenium. But you must know the URL's beforehand. Like shown above.

For example this is what I would do:

1. Make a http request to the URL you find in developer tools
2. With JSON content, use a JSON parser to get a table/array/dictionary natively. You can then traverse this in the native programming language.
3. Use a unicode decoder to get the text in normal text format, there might be a lib to do this, but for example on [this website](https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php) using the "Decode/Unescape Unicode Entities" I was able to get the text.

I hope this helps.

Sample code:

```
import requests;

req = requests.get('https://www.aparat.com/api/fa/v1/video/video/show/videohash/IueKs?pr=1&mf=1&referer=direct')
res = req.json()

#do stuff with res
print(res)
```

Comment: I found this link which has many mp4 file links which may serve your usage case: https://www.aparat.com/api/fa/v1/video/video/show/videohash/IueKs?pr=1&mf=1&referer=direct This does escape some parts of the URL which you may have to consider. (please don't forget to upvote if I helped)